# Are sockets automatically reconnected after the disconnection due to fall in network?

Tags: php, sockets, networking

I am planning to create a chat system and setting the architecture of the application. There are few questions in my mind in which one is left to be answered.

Are network sockets are automatically reconnected after the disconnection in internet ?

**Note:** I am using php sockets extension.

Comment: web sockets .. Ratchet .. http://socketo.me/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, no, websockets do not automatically reconnect.

Most libraries however such as socket.io handle the reconnects automatically for you.

Comment: Sir should i use sessions in client-server socket when creating chatting application ?

Comment: Are sessions necessary for socket based application ?